# ¿Cómo accedo a elemento ul en mi vista?

Tags: html, css, vue.js

Estoy intentando darle estilo, pero no puedo acceder mediante el DOM a el, tampoco tengo muy en claro la jerarquia de las etiquetas, pero aquí está el esqueleto, solamente de la parte en donde está el `<ul>` al que quiero acceder y darle estilo:

```
<div class ="blocks">
                <div id ="package_new_product" v-if = "packagenewProduct == true">
                    <h1> New Product:</h1>
                    <label class ="package_new_product_label">Type:</label>
                    <select class ="package_new_product_input" v-model="type" @change ="searchProduct"><option value="syrup">Syrup</option><option value="pills">Pills</option><option value="capsules">Capsules</option><option value="cream">Cream</option><option value="other">Other</option></select>
                    <label class ="package_new_product_label" >New Product's name:</label>
                    <input class ="package_new_product_input" type="text" v-model="new_name" @input="findProduct" @click="findProduct">

                        <ul v-if = "showlist  == true">
                            <li v-for="i in filteredProducts" @click="setProduct(i)">
                                {{i}}
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                    <label class ="package_new_product_label">New Product's lot:</label>
                    <input class ="package_new_product_input" type="text" v-model="new_lot">
                    <label class ="package_new_product_label">Quantity to be packed:</label>
                    <input class ="package_new_product_input" type="text" v-model="new_quantity">
                    <button type="button" @click="startPacking">Start packing!</button>
                </div>
```

Estoy intentado acceder a el mediante:

```
    #package_new_product ul {
       color: red;
}
```

Accediendo al `<div>` mayor, es decir al `<div>` blocks:

```
    .blocks ul {
       color: red;
}
```

Poniendo su propio `<id>` al `<ul>` tampoco, cómo puedo acceder a el? queda la última forma pero horrible que es agregarle el estilo directamente en la etiqueta, pero no quiero hacer eso xD

Comment: Debes apuntar hasta `li`

Comment: Yo no termino de entender la duda

Answer (score 0):

Te falta un /div al final, supongo que es un error de copy paste. Es la primera vez que veo espacios en blanco antes de los =, menos mal que los navegadores corrigen eso. Prueba con esto.

```css
#package_new_product > ul {
color: red;
background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id ="package_new_product" v-if = "packagenewProduct == true">
                    <h1> New Product:</h1>
                    <label class ="package_new_product_label">Type:</label>
                    <select class ="package_new_product_input" v-model="type" @change ="searchProduct"><option value="syrup">Syrup</option><option value="pills">Pills</option><option value="capsules">Capsules</option><option value="cream">Cream</option><option value="other">Other</option></select>
                    <label class ="package_new_product_label" >New Product's name:</label>
                    <input class ="package_new_product_input" type="text" v-model="new_name" @input="findProduct" @click="findProduct">

                        <ul v-if = "showlist  == true">
                            <li v-for="i in filteredProducts" @click="setProduct(i)">
                                {{i}}
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                    <label class ="package_new_product_label">New Product's lot:</label>
                    <input class ="package_new_product_input" type="text" v-model="new_lot">
                    <label class ="package_new_product_label">Quantity to be packed:</label>
                    <input class ="package_new_product_input" type="text" v-model="new_quantity">
                    <button type="button" @click="startPacking">Start packing!</button>
                </div>
```